# Serial library on Mac OSX

Tags: c, macos

Has someone tried to extend the use of the C code in:
http://www.teuniz.net/RS-232/
to Mac OSX ?
It is limited on compilation to Linux and Windows by preprocessor directives. However, it should be extendible to other POSIX OS, like MAc OSX. I saw some code for Mac that uses more or less the same functions. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried looking for a BSD implementation? Mac OSX is BSD unix at heart.

Comment: I didn't think Macs had serial ports...

Comment: to James: correct, that's why I think it may be compatible. Do you have any suggestion where to start ?

Comment: to Mark: I know Mac probably never had serial ports but I am talking about a vitual serial port (via an USB connection) very useful to talk with electronic devices. I know this is possible because there are a lot of examples.